# R: create a variable based on with 2 conditions

Tags: r

Data is the following (x and dummy are variables referring to the 'id'):

```
   tweet_id <- c(1,2,6,3,4,5,1,2)
    X <- c(0.12426699, 0.12426699, 0.08685890, 0.08685890, 0.08685890, 0.28853901, 0.09102392, 0.09102392)
    id <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4)
    dummy <- c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0)        
    dt <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, X , tweet_id, dummy))
```

I am looking for a function to create a column with the following value:

row 1:
calculate the number sum of all X for tweet_id = 1 for which dummy = 1

row 2:
calculate the number sum of all X for tweet_id = 2 for which dummy = 1

row 3:
calculate the number sum of all X for tweet_id = 6 for which dummy = 1

row 4:
calculate the number sum of all X for tweet_id = 3 for which dummy = 1

....

row 7:
calculate the number sum of all X for tweet_id = 1 for which dummy = 0

row 8:
calculate the number sum of all X for tweet_id = 2 for which dummy = 0

so basically at each row I want to calculate something related to the raw tweet id, based open conditions on the id characteristic 'dummy'

I hope it is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just describing a group by situation here?

Here is a dplyr solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

tweet_id <- c(1,2,6,3,4,5,1,2)
X <- c(0.12426699, 0.12426699, 0.08685890, 0.08685890, 0.08685890, 0.28853901, 0.09102392, 0.09102392)
id <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4)
dummy <- c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0)        
dt <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, X , tweet_id, dummy))


dt_new <- dt %>% 
  group_by(tweet_id, dummy) %>% 
  summarise(X_sum = sum(X))
```

Or add it to your existing data.frame:

```
dt <- dt %>% 
  group_by(tweet_id, dummy) %>% 
  mutate(X_sum = sum(X))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#> # Groups:   tweet_id, dummy [8]
#>      id      X tweet_id dummy  X_sum
#>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1 0.124         1     1 0.124 
#> 2     1 0.124         2     1 0.124 
#> 3     2 0.0869        6     1 0.0869
#> 4     2 0.0869        3     1 0.0869
#> 5     2 0.0869        4     1 0.0869
#> 6     3 0.289         5     0 0.289 
#> 7     4 0.0910        1     0 0.0910
#> 8     4 0.0910        2     0 0.0910
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: it works thank you! but how can a store X_sum as a variable of dt then?

Comment: Added a `mutate` call to it. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `group_by` function from `dplyr`'s library:

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% group_by(tweet_id, dummy) %>% summarise(suma = sum(X))
```

The output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   tweet_id [6]
  tweet_id dummy   suma
     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1        1     0 0.0910
2        1     1 0.124 
3        2     0 0.0910
4        2     1 0.124 
5        3     1 0.0869
6        4     1 0.0869
7        5     0 0.289 
8        6     1 0.0869
```

Good luck!

Comment: how can I store the result as a variable of dt though?

Comment: You can define dt_2 = dt %>% group_by(tweet_id, dummy) %>% summarise(suma = sum(X))

Answer (score 1):

An option with `base R`

```
aggregate(X ~ tweet_id + dummy, dt, FUN = sum)
```